# Parent constructor called by default?

Tags: python, oop, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following example from python `page_object` docs:

```
 from page_objects import PageObject, PageElement
 from selenium import webdriver

 class LoginPage(PageObject):
        username = PageElement(id_='username')
        password = PageElement(name='password')
        login = PageElement(css='input[type="submit"]')

 driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
 driver.get("http://example.com")
 page = LoginPage(driver)
 page.username = 'secret'
 page.password = 'squirrel'
 assert page.username.text == 'secret'
 page.login.click()
```

What bothers me is that we create a `LoginPage` with providing a `driver` to it's constructor, but we haven't define a `__init__` method in `LoginPage` class.

Does that mean that the parent class `PageObject`'s constructor is called with `driver` parameter? I thought that python doesn't implicitly call parent's constructors?

Comment: If you do not define an `__init__` method, the parent implementation is used , normally.

Comment: if there's no child constructor, parent constructor will automatically run .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `__init__` method is just a method and as such python performs the same kind of lookup for it as other methods. If class `B` does not define a method/attribute `x` then python looks up it's base class `A` and so on, until it either finds the attribute/method or fails.

A simple example:

```
>>> class A:
...     def method(self):
...         print('A')
... 
>>> class B(A): pass
... 
>>> class C(B):
...     def method(self):
...         print('C')
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> c = C()
>>> a.method()
A
>>> b.method()  # doesn't find B.method, and so uses A.method
A
>>> c.method()
C
```

The same is with `__init__`: since `LoginPage` does not define `__init__` python looks up the `PageObject` class and finds its definition there.

What is meant when we say that "python doesn't implicitly call parent class constructors" is that **if you define an `__init__` method** the interpreter will just call that method and *not* call all the parent class `__init__`s, and as such if you want to call the parent class constructor you have to do so explicitly.

Note the difference among these classes:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...         print('A')
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     pass
... 
>>> class B2(A):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print('B')
... 
>>> class B3(A):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print('B3')
...         super().__init__()
... 
>>> A()
A
<__main__.A object at 0x7f5193267eb8>
>>> B()  # B.__init__ does not exists, uses A.__init__
A
<__main__.B object at 0x7f5193267ef0>
>>> B2()  # B2.__init__ exists, no call to A.__init__
B
<__main__.B2 object at 0x7f5193267eb8>
>>> B3()  # B3.__init__exists, and calls to A.__init__ too
B3
A
<__main__.B3 object at 0x7f5193267ef0>
```